# Is there any problem to conduct instrumental variables analysis with binary endogenous variable and binary outcome?

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables

I would like to introduce "instrumental variables" in my study.

In many cases, the outcome (dependent variable; DV) is a continuous variable.

However, my study design has binary outcome (DV) and endogenous variable (EV) is also binary.

As I saw many materials, most of them present "continuous EV and continuous DV".

In stata, I saw that ivprobit package can analysis IV with binary DV. On the other hand, I have not seen the analysis with binary EV.

So, is there any statistical problem to to conduct instrumental variables analysis with binary endogenous variable and binary outcome?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the bivariate probit command (`biprobit` in Stata, recursive version). User-written `cmp` is another option.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thank you for your comments. I will check it.